# How to call a method defined in a UIView controller from a UIView placed within the ViewController

Tags: xcode, uiview, methods, call

How to call a method defined in a UIView controller from a UIView placed within the ViewController.

If this isn't possible then how would I make a button that is placed within the UIView call a segue?

spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It took me a day but I managed to find a simple workaround.

In the UIView.h create a UIVIewController property and then in your ViewController set the UIViews property to .self .

Having done this within the UIView you can access that property and from there call prepare for segue.